# how to make javascript function return true without posting the photo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code to check if the user loaded his photo:

```
if ($('#photoFlag').val() == "0") {    
    alert("sorry you didn't post your photo！");
    return false;
}
```

this is the function to check whether the user has posted the photo,  he could get to the next page only if he uploaded the photo.

if the user just want to get to the next page without posting the photo, is it possible?

is there any method that make this javascript code lose effect?

Ps:user haS no control over the code,  he **MUST** ALWAYS upload the photos

Comment: I don't think the value will ever be 0.

Comment: @user, I assume you do not have control over that code?

Comment: user kind of like a hacker,i think

Comment: Re: your edit, are you asking if that code will prevent an reasonably-determined attacker from proceeding to the next page without posting a photo? Because if that's the case, the answer is **No**. The client (Javascript code running in a browser in your case) should never be trusted.

Comment: then in which way can an attacker make it lose effect? how to prevent?

Comment: @user, you cannot prevent that. What if I turn off Javascript altogether in my browser? Your code won't run (obviously), but the form will still be submitted because it does not require scripting to be enabled to do so. The only solution to your problem is to validate that information server-side, as you should always do.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply ask for confirmation from the user. Something like:

```
if ($('#photoFlag').val() == "0") {    
 var choice = confirm("Do you want to proceed without posting your photo?");
 return choice;
}
```

Comment: or return confirm("Do you want to proceed without posting your photo?");

Comment: yep, i thought about it, then left it as it is for clarify.. :)